# Azure Data Factory Expression Property Containing Dot

Tags: json, azure

I have a WebActivity that returns json that looks like this:

```
{
    "transactions.json": "https://someurl",
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "x-amz-apigw-id": "Tbks6H5fIAMF3EA="
    }
}
```

I'm trying to parse it like this:

```
@activity('Get File URL').output.transactions.json
```

which fails of course.

How should I reference the property "transactions.json"?

Answer (score 0):

@activity('Get File URL').output['transactions.json']